# Magento: Facebook like box disappearing after clicking on "Like Page" button (www.fashnq.com - check in footer)

Tags: facebook, magento

This issue is resolved. Thank you.

---

Facebook like box is placed in footer of our website. When we click on "Like Page" button in the Facebook like box, a window will be opened to give our facebook credentials. After entering our facebook login details, the facebook like box is disappearing.

can someone please help us in identifying the issue. You can check this issue in www.fashnq.com in footer.

Comment: Can’t reproduce. Clicking “Like Page” makes the button text change to “liked”, and that’s it – plugin doesn’t “disappear” or anything like that.

Comment: Please check again, please refresh the page and try again. I have reproduced this issue just now. If you are not logged in into facebook page in your browser, then when you click on like page button in facebook like box, it will ask for facebook credentials after giving id & password of FB, the plugin will disappear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

That is a weird code for the Page Plugin, you should always use the code from the generator:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Change the settings and the URL and click on "Get Code":

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FashnQ/" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/FashnQ/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/FashnQ/">FashnQ.com</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I am pretty sure that´s the problem. Don´t forget to include the JS SDK, the code is in the generator too.

Comment: Thank you @luschn for your response. I will implement the solution you have provided and update the result here.